# Invert last two subfolders of the directory structure

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, directory, perl

Basically, I request a unix way (bash, perl, etc) to invert the last two subfolders, like in this windows question:
https://superuser.com/questions/221/how-can-i-invert-a-directory-structure
This is an example, the objective is to modify the path of lots of files.

```
i.e. 
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/myfile
to:
/dir1/dir2/dir4/dir3/myfile
```

Comment: Can we assume that there is not already a dir1/dir2/dir4 directory? What is the input to this process — the path to myfile?

Comment: show `tree /dir1/dir2`

Comment: You are unhappy with `mv /dir1/dir2/dir3/{dir4,dir3}  ;  mv /dir1/dir2/{dir3,dir4}` ?

Comment: Jeff Shaller, I am not sure what I can answer, but it would be better to just check it in the process. and create it only when necessary. I think of several files in the example subfolder dir4. I am not sure if the input should be every file or if it would be the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution with four subdirectories you could use something like this:

```
for p4 in */*/*/*
do
    p3="${p4%/*}" p2="${p3%/*}" d4="${p4/*\/}" d3="${p3/*\/}"
    mv "$p4" "$p3/$d3" && mv "$p3" "$p2/$d4"
done
```

It does no error checking for the presence of a target directory before it attempts the transposition. In this situation you will end up with the third level directory being duplicated. For example, `a/b/d` exists and we are going to transpose `a/b/c/d`, we will end up with `a/b/d/c/c`.

If you have too many directories matching `*/*/*/*` you could split it further with an additional loop per level. With care this will obviate the need to derive paths `$p2` and `$p3`.